# How to make stencils for spray painting

Tags: add-on, import, image

In Blender 2.93 I want starting from a text image to create stencils that I can print in 3D and use to spray paint text on a real flat or curved object. I understand Blender can accept my text as a .bmp file that I may create in MSPaint. It seems the Blender function I need is Import ImageAsPlane. But from the on-line manual I can find only that this requires an Add-on which as a beginner I am unable to find. Please give step-by-step help.

Comment: @moonboots The tutorial video describes the stencil texture mapping function. That does not help me create a real stencil that I can print in 3D and use to spray real paint.

Comment: @moonboots I think not. This defines what I want to make in a 3D printer: STENCIL n. a piece of card or plastic with a shape or letters cut out of it. You place it on a surface and paint over it to make a design on something.

Comment: oh ok I completely misunderstood what you meant, so if you have b&w bitmap images you can convert to curve then to mesh

Comment: @moonboots As a beginner I may manage this with step-by-step help. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: is it what you're looking for? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zkJC1LJycc

Comment: you want to import a b&w image of a letter, convert it to a mesh (i.e. a 3D object) so that you can 3D print afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your b&w image to svg in an image editor, then import the svg, then convert to mesh, etc...

Another method is to fully convert within Blender:

- Add (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) an *Image > Reference*, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to reset the rotation if necessary.
- Header menu > *Object > Convert > Trace Image to Grease Pencil*.
- Move the result and right click > *Convert To > Polygon Curve*.
- Again move the result, select the outline object and right click > *Convert To > Mesh*.
- Switch to *Edit* mode, select the mesh and fill with <kbd>F</kbd>.
- Extrude with <kbd>E</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

From the Edit menu, select 'Preferences' then the 'Addons' tab (1). Type 'image' into the search field (2)
then check the 'Import Export: Images as Planes' entry (3).
[image]

You'll now find the 'Images as Planes' entry at the bottom of the File > Import menu.

Comment: Thank you, I have imported my .bmp image. It appears in the 3D view as a plain plane. How do I drill out the black areas and leave the white areas as solid (or the other way round) ?

Comment: There's a YT video by 3D Tudor [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bZmaylLM1g) which should show you the technique. Although the start of it uses Photoshop, you can just as easily use Gimp or Krita to actually produce the initial image.

Answer (score 0):

Use displacement modifier. Apply the black and white texture as displacement. Prepare the texture, UVs of the model and then apply the displacement and you have a stamp ready to print.
[image]